# DELETE Statement with subquery strange behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with which I'm executing a delete statement.  When I select a column with an invalid column name it throws an error.  But when I use the column name of the first table it just deletes the records.

//Query:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (ID INT)
GO
CREATE TABLE FOOBAR (NUMBER INT)
GO

INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO FOO VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO FOOBAR VALUES(1)
GO

-- The following will raise an error
SELECT ID FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1
GO
--Server: Msg 207, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
--Invalid column name 'ID'.


-- The following statement will delete the entire table
DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1)
GO
--(3 row(S) affected)
```

When I used the Alias name it worked fine. Is it a bug or something else?

How does this happen?

Comment: DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN
(SELECT Number FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1)
GO

Comment: Update like above code you have return ID instead of number

Comment: Please read [Qualifying Column Names in Subqueries](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178050(v=sql.105).aspx): " If a column does not exist in the table referenced in the FROM clause of a subquery, it is implicitly qualified by the table referenced in the FROM clause of the outer query"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following statement the inner select will get the column `ID` from table `FOO` and not from table `FOOBAR`.

```
DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1)
```

In order to make this more obvious you could try adding Alliases to the tables and do a select instead of a delete, just to see the results:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO F WHERE ID IN
(SELECT F.ID FROM FOOBAR FB WHERE FB.NUMBER = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column called `ID` in the table `FOOBAR`. It has one column, and it is called `NUMBER`. Your select statement should look like:

```
SELECT NUMBER FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1;
```

To complete the delete where `NUMBER` in `FOOBAR` equals `ID` in `FOO` looks like:

```
DELETE FROM FOO WHERE ID IN
(SELECT NUMBER FROM FOOBAR WHERE NUMBER = 1);
```